# Exchange 2010 - how to hide first hop IP from mail headers

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam

My company has an Exchange server which forward outgoing emails to a mailhub, which has a spam filter.

(user)----(company's Exchange)----(mailhub with antispam)----(the world)

It happens that my users send emails with the company's Exchange using their home DSL connections, which quite frequently are blacklisted by RBL lists.
The mailhub look at the headers, see the incriminated IP address as the fist hop and drop the message, thinking it's SPAM.

How can I instruct Exchange 2010 to remove the first hop IP address from the headers ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't these users using Outlook Anywhere/RPC over HTTP from home? If they were, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You are right, but the problem is: clients. Many of them use OSX/Mail or Linux/Thunderbird with IMAP. Same problem with smartphones that only supports IMAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exchange 2010 you can rewrite some headers but not the "received" header. So the answer to your question is "you can't".

At least natively with Exchange, maybe a third party program could do it...

If Outlook Anywhere is not a option (as suggested by  joeqwerty), I would say that you should force home users to pass trough a VPN to send corporate email.

You could also have the address of the Exchange server  trusted by the anti-spam, at least for this check, but since it seems you actually relay email from any public IP addresses I would not advise it.